# Check exact match of a word in a line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

A variable holds the string as,
nameList="abc bcd bcde cdefg"
and another variable has string as, checkname="bcd".

Now i have to check if $checkname is present in $nameList or not. It should search for exact value only.

For eg. if we check for "bcd" it should throw yes, if we check for "bc" it should throw no. I need this condition check in "if" condition

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: all the above are checking for complete line, but not a substring in that line

Comment: To check for a space-separated literal word, try  `case " $nameList " in *" $checkname "*) echo yes;; esac` - notice the quoted spaces.

Comment: @impika Yeah, they do. Sorry for the wrongly marked duplicate. I was mislead by your formulation `exact value only`. I voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple for loop could do this :

```
for word in $nameList 
do 
   if [ "$checkname" == "$word" ] 
   then 
        echo found 
        break  
   fi
done
```

Comment: It works, so does it mean a string with spaces will be treated like an array?

Comment: In this case the for loop considers spaces as word separators, so it basically does word splitting.

Comment: Ok good. Thanks.